# Customer not login after upgrade magento to 1.9, I also try to add form key in login.phtml. But still not working

Tags: magento-1.9

I am suffering a problem with customer login and is only working when i remove my browser cookie then its working, i have tried adding the form key in login.phtml file also. But this solution also is not working.

Can any one please let me know, what is the problem.

Comment: can you pls share both magento version?